# Search for words contains special letters

Tags: google-sheets

In the word list I want to search for words that contain certain letters, and at the same time these words do not contain other letters. These letters can be repeated more than once in the same word, and the order of the letters within the word is not important. I tried this formula:

```
=filter(A2:A,byrow(A2:A,lambda(Σ,sum(index(search(D3:F3,Σ))))))
```

But I need to modify it to exclude words that contain letters other than the required letters.

This screenshot shows what I mean:
[image]

This is the link to the sheet:
[sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QLpH9VLlITSHItn5heBO8nkzBLo9gfAwwEIFZLMtTsU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(word_, A2:A,
     Λ,map(word_,lambda(Σ,join(,unique(index(mid(Σ,sequence(len(Σ)),1)))))),
     filter(word_,map(Λ,lambda(Σ,sum(search(D3:F3,Σ)^0)))=3, len(Λ)=3))
```

[image]